# Backup and Restore sqlite db during new version release

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, sqlite, version-control

I am working on an iPAD application. When a new version is released, I add the version number on the server side db and call it through a webservice and check with the build version of the app. If there is change in the version I am calling a URL to install the new version of the app. What will be the possible solution, not to lose my data from the iPAD app and once the new app is installed I use back the same sqlite db. FYI... I am not using any MDM, and installing the app through an URL. Let me know if I need to explain more in detail.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, app version update usually reset the data to the bundle as packaged in the archive (ipa). The user data in the databases then become lost. (Note: this may have changed in IOS 7 because of the announced incremental update options but I have never been able to check it out).

My way around this is to provide a backup restore facility that creates a Plist in the /Document Folder. this allows the user to extract his data through iTunes File sharing, then restore it back if he or she wishes. If you have a server though, a better way would be to create folders for registered users and program the facility to back / restore from the server. Prompt the user to use the backup prior to any update, and prompt the user to restore data from the server (if available and the database is empty).